# Angular 8.3 with Angular Material wont work on Mozilla 34 and 45

Tags: css, typescript, angular-material, angular8

[Here is the problem on Mozilla version 34 and 45](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALYOn.png)   while Mozilla 52 and IE 11 are working fine.

Iv started to remove component by component and it turns out that what is making the problem is mat-sidenav, I may be wrong there I'm not 100% sure.
Box-Shadow

*ERROR" Error: The animation trigger "transform" has failed to build due to the following errors:
 - The provided animation property "box-shadow" is not a supported CSS property for animations*

[here is a photo of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KikLu.png)  does anyone had a similar problem and is willing to help :)

Comment: your image is pretty big. You should use https://pastebin.com/ for such purpose.